# Is there a way to represent bitwise xor with logical shifts or addition/subtraction?

Tags: c, syntax, operators

Just wondering if the operator "^" in C can be represented with shifts or subtraction/addition of signed integers.

Comment: Have you consider using combination of AND, OR and NOT?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate#Alternatives

Comment: Do you need to represent it in a easily understandable readable format(highly unlikely to be possible) or you want alternative way to synthesize the behavior(possible with function of few steps)?

Comment: @AlokSave The latter. I want to know if the behavior can be mimicked with very rudimentary operations.

Comment: @Steady: [This](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/bitmath/#Xor) should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A   B   A^B   A+B
0   0    0    00
0   1    1    01
1   0    1    01
1   1    0    10
```

so Xor, can be looked as addition's first bit only (no carry out)

let's implement that :

```
unsigned char a, b;

unsigned char c, answer =0;
int i;

for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
   c = (a>>i)+(b>>i);  // bit ny bit starting from lsb

   c <<= 7;   // get lost the carry out of addition
   c >>= 7;   // we care only about one-bit result

   c <<= i;   // shift it to its correct position
   answer += c;  // add it to result
}

printf("%X\n", answer);
```

find a testing example [here](http://ideone.com/xITdOs)